# Extremely frustrating behavior with WindowsError (Error 32) to remove temporary files

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, gdal

I have to remove the tiff files extracted into temporary directory after completing the required tasks (reading, calculating, and resulting the outfile).

The following error attaching with one of the tiff files does not allow removing the files, and stops the program:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Otherwise working code is as follows:

```
import os, glob, subprocess, gdal, numpy as np

files = glob.glob('*.txt')
temp_dir = 'E:\\td\\'

for r in files:

    fi = open (r, 'r')   
    files = fi.read().splitlines()
    winrar = 'C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\Rar.exe'
    extracts = [subprocess.call([winrar, 'x', f, temp_dir],shell=True) for f in files]
    fi.close()
    tiff_files = glob.glob(temp_dir + '*.tif')
    inrasters = [gdal.Open(i) for i in tiff_files] 

    data = np.array([e.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32) for e in inrasters])
    data_mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)

    outdriver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outraster = outdriver.Create('..\\outfile.tif',5000,5000,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
    outraster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data_mean)

    inrasters, outraster  = None, None

    for x in tiff_files:
        os.remove(x)
```

Extremely frustrated because I could not figure out what the application is using that one file, and how to solve it. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Even if I reboot the Windows, the same error repeats.

Comment: You dont use `tiff_files` anywhere, so all the code you are showing seems irrelevant to the problem. You can check file handles with processexplorer, that might point you to the application claiming the file. And with gdal you can actively close a file with `ds = None`

Comment: I think temp_files should be tiff_files. There is no definition of temp_files.

Comment: In that case doing `[ds = None for ds in inrasters]` before the last two lines might help.

Comment: @Rutger Kassies actually temp_files was mistakenly typed here in the question instead of tiff_files. but what I am really testing the code is using tiff_files. I have also corrected this error in the question.

Comment: @Jayanth Koushik yes, I have corrected that typing error

Comment: Then please check my answer; There was a similar question and closing the files is required on Windows.

Comment: @Rutger Kassies [ds = None for ds in inrasters] could not solve unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this before the delete loop:

```
 del e
```

Apparently the line `inrasters, outraster  = None, None` is an attempt to close the files, but that only works if `inrasters` is the only reference to the files. The list comprehension that builds `data` leaves `e` as a reference to the last file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close files before you can remove them. Close all open files before the last two lines.

Comment: trying to closing the files using os.close(x) results error that an integer is required

Comment: You have opened the file using gdal; please check the documentation to see how to close open gdal objects. os.close requires a file descriptor.

Comment: According to the gdal docs, the way of closing the file is what I have already used as inrasters = None